# CSS Media Query Not Grouping Conditions Correctly

Tags: html, css

I have the following css:

```
    /* iPhone 4 Landscape */
@media only screen 
    and (max-device-width: 480px) 
    and (min-device-width: 320px) 
    and (orientation: landscape) {

    .dropdown-menu{
        height: 210px;  
    }
}

/* iPhone 4 Portrait */
@media only screen  
    and (max-device-width: 480px)
    and (min-device-width: 320px)
    and (orientation: portrait) {

    .dropdown-menu{
        height: 370px;  
    }
}


/* iPhone 5 Landscape */
@media only screen      
    and (max-device-width: 568px)
    and (min-device-width: 320px) 
    and (orientation: landscape) {

    .dropdown-menu{
        height: 210px;  
    }
}
```

My problem is that the iPhone 5 condition seems to be taking affect on iPhone 4.  I know it's effectively doing the same thing (setting the height to 210px) but is there are reason for this?  I'm testing it in chrome's phone emulator.

It seems like it's only seeing the one condition of min-device-width being 320px and using that query as opposed to using all of the conditions together.

Comment: how would you know if it's taking the other condition? as you said, they are doing the exact same thing... add a different change in and see if it is doing that as well.

Comment: When you inspect element on the .dropdown-menu its showing that it's using the 568x320 css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the iphone 4 screen will fullfill both media queries (resolution is lower than max iphone 5 media query) and the iphone 5 is the last one. Being the last one it overrides the iphone 4 media query.

Comment: thanks, do you know if there is anyway to group the conditions to prevent this from happening?  I would only want the iphone 5 to work when all conditions (320 min width, 568 max width and orientation landscape) are met.

Comment: All conditions are being met. The iPhone 4 has a width less than or equal to 568px, but greater than or equal to 320px and the orientation is landscape.